# How to add a new Stage to my default Stage?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex3

I want to add a new Stage called `field` to the default one (i need to place different elements on it later). And then I want to add `myBitmap` to the `field`. But nothing happens. I don't understand what should i do.

```
var field:Stage = new Stage();
field.x = 200;
field.y = 200;
field.width = 300;
field.height = 300;
stage.addChild(field);

var bdWidth:Number = 100;
var bdHeight:Number = 100;
var bdTransparent:Boolean = true;
var bdFillColorARGB:uint = 0xFF007090;
var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bdWidth, bdHeight, bdTransparent, bdFillColorARGB);
var myBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapData);
myBitmap.x = 10;
myBitmap.y = 10;
field.addChild(myBitmap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have multiple stages in an SWF. Use a `Sprite` instead.

The unique `Stage` object in an SWF is created automatically by Flash player. Even if you load another SWF into the first SWF and access `stage` from the newly loaded SWF or its children, you will still get the same `stage` object.

Comment: Unless its an Adobe Air "WindowedApplication" that opens additional native windows, then each window has its own stage and display list.